# Can I turn a ceiling light into an overhead projector mount?

Tags: electrical, uk, projector

I want to put a projector into one of the rooms of my new place. Is it possible to remove the pendant light, convert it into a UK mains outlet and still use the light switch to provide the power? Or would there simply be too much load required from the projector?

Comment: Can't really say without knowing what the power requirements are for the projector... But your idea sounds good _on paper_...

Comment: One thing to consider is that there's a lot of stress on the lightbulb in a projector as it warms up/cools off. You want to reduce those cycles when you can. Using a lightswitch to control power to the projector risks undue wear on them, and they're usually expensive. Plugging into an always-on outlet and using the power button on the remote/projector itself is probably your best from a longevity perspective.

Comment: Agree 100% with @Havegooda! I'm sure designs have improved, but even LED bulbs bright enough for projection produce a _lot_ of heat. When you turn the projector off with its remote or physical button, the fan continues to run a while (just like on your car) to cool the bulb. Without that fan running, you could be replacing £100 bulbs on a regular basis.

Comment: In addition to power requirements, you have to consider the weight of the projector vs the weight of the light that was there. You don't want your expensive projector to pull the box out of the ceiling and come crashing down to the ground, or someone's head.

Comment: With regards to weight, not sure about UK but in the US there are boxes /mounting designed for fans which is what I'd recommend for a projector.

Comment: Do your electric codes require a switched outlet for lighting at the entrance to the room?

Comment: Can't see why not; lighting circuits running tens+ of halogen downlight  spotlights need more power than a projector. The other commenters make good points; you might want to bypass the light switches so that don't power off the projector any more (take the switch off and wire the permanent and switched wires to the same terminal) for reasons mentioned. How do you get the image to the projector? Wireless? or are you still going to have an HDMI cable going up the wall and along the ceiling?

Comment: Is the plan to not have a light at all, by the way? I mean.. cinema rooms benefit from the dark but it's nice to be able to get in and out without falling over stuff you can't see! I ask because it looks like there are generally two wiring strategies; power to the ceiling and power to the switch. If your house is power to the ceiling you can keep the switched light.. Take all switches off and post a picture of what's behind them, or take the cover off the light and photo that so we can see how many wires are there

Comment: (1) If the lighting circuit doesn't have an earth, then you won't be able to use it for a non-lighting device. (2) In any case, check the rules as to whether you're allowed to put a non-lighting device on a lighting circuit. (3) While you're there, check if doing this would require an electrician anyway (Part P, etc).

Answer (score 1):

In theory this could work, but I suspect you could have difficult questions to answer in case of an inspection.

I picked a random projector from google: https://www.projectors.co.uk/sony-vpl-phz60-projector/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIkPfusrLG-gIVDJ7tCh1XpA0DEAQYASABEgI1LfD_BwE#additional

The specs say this has a power requirement of 418W at 240V, which should be within the capabilities of a normal UK lighting circuit (5A fuse or 6A MCB gives you ~1.25 - 1.5kW), but also say a current requirement of up to 4.4A, which is pushing towards the limit of a lighting circuit, and you may start to get nuisance trips.

Depending on the wiring the light fitting currently has you may need to add a junction box to replace the switch connections currently made in the fitting. A socket fixture will not have the extra terminals necessary. Also standard UK back boxes and socket faceplates are expected to be installed in walls, not ceilings, so you may need extra work to ensure it is properly secure.

Given that you'll also need to do something with the cable for the video feed, why not add the power feed alongside that.